# Polynomial : $P(x) \mid P(x^n)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a  non-constant polynomial.

Prove that if $P(x) \mid P(x^n)$ and $P(a) = 0$ then $a=0$ or $\mid \,a \mid = 1$.

Edited work : For $n\geq 2$,

Since $P(a) \mid P(a^n)$ , so $a^n$ is root of polynomial $P(x)$

we have $P(a) \mid P(a^n) \mid P(a^{n^2}) \mid P(a^{n^3}) \mid ...$

Similarly, $a, a^n, a^{n^2}, ...$ are roots of the polynomial.

If all roots are distinct, $P(x)$ would be constant polynomial that is impossible.

so there exist $l, k$ such that $a^{n^l}=a^{n^k}$

$a^{n^l}(a^{n^k-n^l}-1)=0$

so $a=0$ or $a^{n^k-n^l}=1$

That is $a=0$ or $\mid \,a \mid = 1$.

(Please read Bill Dubuque's helpful comment)

Comment: The expression $P(a)\mid P(a^n)$ does not make much sense. Note that $P(a)$ is not integer, in general. Under the hypothesis $P(a)=0$ is even worse.

Comment: Is $n\ge 2$? Otherwise there are counterexamples everywhere.

Comment: @ajotatxe "even worse" is wrong / misleading, since $\ 0\mid c\iff c = 0\ $ follows by the  definition of divisibility. Further, divisibility makes sense in any ring, not just for integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite correct. In particular, $P(a^n)=0\Leftrightarrow P(a)=0$ does not necessarily hold : only one implication does, namely $P(a)=0\Rightarrow P(a^n)=0$.

Indeed, $P(x)|P(x^n)$ means that there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $P(x^n)=P(x)\cdot Q(x)$; and then of course if $P(a)=0$, then $P(a^n)=P(a)\cdot Q(a)=0\cdot Q(a)=0$.

Here's a hint on how to finish the proof : since the implication $P(a)=0\Rightarrow P(a^n)=0$ holds for all $a\in \Bbb R$, you can iterate this result, and thus any root $a$ gives a sequence of roots $a,a^n,(a^n)^n=a^{n^2},\dots$ (assuming $n\geq 2$ as Henning Makholm mentioned in his comment and his answer) But a polynomial cannot have infinitely many roots, so this sequence must repeat itself at some points. What does that imply?

Comment: Thank you, Arnaud D and Henning Makholm. Please check if my edited work above is correct or not.

Comment: @carat Yes, your proof is correct now, but you seem to be implicitly using $\, 0\mid c\iff c=0,\,$ when inferring $\,0=P(a)\mid P(a^n)\,\Rightarrow\, P(a^n) = 0,\,$ which may confuse some readers.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, thank you. In fact, I mean "if...then...", please let me know what line that may confuse the readers so I can correct it.

Comment: @carat Readers who have not studied algebra or number theory often don't know that $\,0\mid c\,$ is well-defined. To avoid such confusion write it *explicitly* $\,P(a) Q(a) = P(a^n)\,$ so $\,P(a)=0\,\Rightarrow\, P(a^n)=0\ \ \ $

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your intermediate conclusion

> If $P(a^n)=0$, then $P(a)=0$

is not true. A counterexample would be
$$ n=2 \qquad a=-1 \qquad P(x) = x-1 $$
Then $P(a^2)=0$ but $P(a)=-2$.

---

You need to go the other way and argue that if $P(a)=0$ then $P(a^n)=0$ too.

**Hint:** $P(x) \mid P(x^n)$ means that there is a polynomial $Q$ such that $P(x)Q(x) = P(x^n)$.

Comment: Let $P(x)=x-2, n=2, a=2$. Then $P(a)=0$, but $P(a^n)\neq0$.

Comment: @SahibaArora: But $x-2$ does not divide $x^2-2$.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes under that hypothesis it will hold.